# Advice regarding degrees of freedom and number of covariates in my model

Tags: sample-size, ancova

I want to apply ANCOVA on my data set. I have

1. A continuous dependent
2. A categorical factor with 4 levels
3. A continuous covariate

I want to apply ANCOVA on these variables in male and female population subsets. $$H_0: M_1=M_2=M_3=M_4$$ in men,        $$H_0:M_1=M_2=M_3=M_4$$ in women

(the average of the dependent variable among the level of the categorical variable in male,the average of the dependent variable among the level of the categorical variable in female).

Now If I  include sex as a new variable in the model (instead of applying separate ANCOVA model for men and female)  then how many covariates will we have in the model?

I want to calculate the sample size and I need to know

1. The degrees of freedom
2. Number of groups
3. Number of covariates

Comment: What do M1 to M4 stand for?

Comment: @  mdewey, Hi. I want to test the average of the dependent variable among the levels of the categorical variable in male and also test the average of the dependent variable among the levels of the categorical variable in female. I am not interested to compare male and female together.